# Adding "required" placeholder text for all required fields (Angular Material)

Tags: html, angular, input, angular-material, placeholder

I'm trying to show a clarifying "Required" placeholder text for all input fields that have "required" attribute set to true.

So basically the same as

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input formControlName="fieldName" matInput required="true" placeholder="Required">
</mat-form-field>
```

But programmatically for all required fields. Form fields "required" status is set at the component initialization based on various conditions.

If there is a way to do this for all components / pages of the angular app, not just for one component that would be even better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply a directive to several elements we use the selector

In this case the selector is a tag "input" with an attribute "formControl" or attribute "formControlName"

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[formControlName],input[formControl]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class AddPlaceholderDirective {
  constructor(private control: NgControl, private element: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.control.control?.hasValidator(Validators.required) &&
        !this.element.nativeElement.placeholder) {
      this.element.nativeElement.placeholder = 'required';
    }
  }
}
```

**Update** a brief explain:

A directive can be "structural directives" and "[attributes directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#attribute-directives)".

An attribute directive give new characteristic to our htmlElements or even to ours components, but How works?

When we have a selector like `[myDirective]` all the HTMLElements with this "attribute" are improve with the new characteristic. (this is the reason for the name of attribute directive)

e.g., when have

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
     console.log("I'm a super div")
  }
}

//and write

<div myDirective>Hello</div>
```

This div it's not a simple div, else a "super div" (yes, only say in console "I'm a super div", but make "something different that a simple div")

Well, the structural directive have a "selector" that in general is a simple string between ``` [``] ``` but the selectors can be different, see [the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector)

So, a selector like `input[formControl]` give new super power to all the input with an attribute "formControl" and a selector like `input[type="radio"]` give new super power to all the input with an attribute type who was "radio".

I know that formControl was another directive but it's also an attribute.

NOTE: the good of an "attribute directive" is that, as is applied to an HTMLElement or to a Component, we can get in constructor the htmlElement or the component this is the reason we can use

```
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef,control:NgControl){}
```

The "elementRef" we have in all the attributes directives and is the own "htmlElement" where we add the attribute.

The "ngControl" is because we have an input with ngModel of FormControl or FormControlName

Comment: I have never used selector directives, how do I tell a component/template that I want to use this directive at the template?

Comment: @mikkom, I update the answer with two links and a brief explanation. The only that remember import the directive -you use the array "declarations" if you're using Modules or in the imports array if you're using standalone components. NOTE: In this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-eepnwy?file=src%2Fmain.ts) I forked the stackblitz of Narem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a directive that will do it for you, we can create a directive `addPlaceholder` which will first get the `formControlName` using `getAttribute` and then through the `controlContainer.control` get the parent form, then finally we get access to the `FormControl` of the element, check if has `required` validator and then finally set the placeholder

Please find below working example!

directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[addPlaceholder]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class AddPlaceholderDirective {
  @Input() customPlaceholder = 'required';

  constructor(
    @Inject(ControlContainer) private container: ControlContainer,
    private element: ElementRef
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const formControlName =
      this.element.nativeElement.getAttribute('formControlName');
    const control: FormControl = this.container?.control?.get(
      formControlName
    ) as FormControl;
    if (control.hasValidator(Validators.required)) {
      this.element.nativeElement.placeholder = 'required!';
    }
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { AddPlaceholderDirective } from './add-placeholder.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, AddPlaceholderDirective],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="test" addPlaceholder/>
  <input type="text" formControlName="test2" addPlaceholder/>
  <input type="text" formControlName="test3" addPlaceholder/>
</form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  form = new FormGroup({
    test: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    test2: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    test3: new FormControl(''),
  });
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ys5kye?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fadd-placeholder.directive.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: This would require adding the directive to all fields which would be almost identical to the example I gave (using placeholder text). I'm looking for a way to update all fields programmatically without needing to update every element on the template.